# Having Issues with side-menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem in my side-menu bar. First, I want a custom scrollbar for the side-menu bar, which is working well but has issues. When I am try to hover to last parent menu the sub-menu position appears upper side but at the same time I try to hover to that parent sub-menu and this time the sub-menu's position changes to down, which I would like to know how to fix.

You can see demo of what Issues having. when scroll to last menu that time having problem(which show in GIF Image Demo)

Here Link where get all HTML/CSS/JS https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6tYK76Lu9DkWnlMM2g2SXUyZkE

[image]

**HTML CODE which I am trying for that**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin - Bootstrap Admin Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-dropdownhover.css">
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <!-- custom scrollbar stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">


    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fm.scrollator.jquery.css" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-dropdownhover.css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
.verticle-menu {width: 100%; float: left;}
.verticle-menu #info {font-size: 18px; color: #555; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 25px;}
.verticle-menu a { color: #000000; font-size: 12px; text-transform: uppercase;}
.verticle-menu .scrollbar {margin-left: 0px; float: left; /*height: 700px;*/ background: #fff; overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 100%;}
.verticle-menu .force-overflow {min-height: 450px; border-right: 1px solid #cccccc; height: 100%;}
.verticle-menu #wrapper {text-align: center; width: 500px; margin: auto;}
.verticle-menu #style-3::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background-color: #fff;}
.verticle-menu #style-3::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 6px; background-color: #fff;}
.verticle-menu #style-3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background-color: #fff;}
.verticle-menu .wrapper {position: relative;}
.verticle-menu ul {width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;}
.verticle-menu ul {color: white; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; padding: 0;}
.verticle-menu li {position: static; list-style: none;}
.verticle-menu li .wrapper {position: absolute; z-index: 10; display: none; left: 100% !important;}
.verticle-menu li:hover > .wrapper {display: block;}
.verticle-menu li {line-height: 34px; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; font-size: 12px; padding: 0px 5px;}
.verticle-menu li ul {margin: 0;}
.verticle-menu li span {color: #000;}
.verticle-menu li .wrapper {cursor: auto; border: 1px solid #cccccc; margin-left: -1px; width: 100%; margin-top: -1px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 0px; padding:0px; border-bottom:none;}
.verticle-menu li .wrapper li {line-height: 34px; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; font-size: 12px; padding: 0px 7px;}
.verticle-menu li .wrapper li a:hover {color: #F70004;}
.verticle-menu li:nth-child(2n) {background: #fff;}
.verticle-menu li:nth-child(2n+1) {background: #fff;}
.verticle-menu li.parent {cursor: pointer;}

#scrollable_div1 {height: 700px; width: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #cccccc;}

.topcls{top: auto !important;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="col-lg-12 padding0">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <h4 style="color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase;display:block; text-align:center;">HEADER</h4>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 padding0">
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div style="width:12%; float:left; z-index:2; position:fixed;">
                <div class="verticle-menu">
                    <div id="scrollable_div1">
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                    <span>Menu 01</span>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                    <span>Menu 02</span>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 03</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 04</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 05</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 06</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 07</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 08</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 09</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 10</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 11</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 12</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 13</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 14</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 15</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 16</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 17</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 18</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 19</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 20</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 21</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 22</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 23</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 24</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 25</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent dropdown dropdown-inline">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
                                        <span class="main-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span>Menu 26</span>
                                    </a>
                                        <div class="wrapper dropdown-menu">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 01</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 02</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 03</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 04</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu 05</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            <div id="page-wrapper" style="width:88%; float:left; z-index:0; position:absolute; right:0;">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                // Contain which i removed 
                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fm.scrollator.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-dropdownhover.js"></script>
    <script>

        (function ($) {
            $(window).resize(function () {
                $('#scrollable_div1').height($(window).height() - 52);
            });
            $(window).on("load", function () {

                $('#scrollable_div1').height($(window).height() - 52);
                $('#scrollable_div1').scrollator();

            });
        })(jQuery);


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you advance.

Comment: the complete page is good, but the scripts are not present in the index.html, can you provide a jsfiddle with the issue alone, it will help in debugging quickly

Comment: U need all js files @NarenMurali

Comment: Just the js files needed for sidebar and having the issue...if possible jsfiddle

Comment: we have js files which used but not possible jsfiddle because we are not getting what issue we are having @NarenMurali

Comment: Here  link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6tYK76Lu9DkWnlMM2g2SXUyZkE  where you get all with HTML/CSS/JS etc all  @NarenMurali Hope it will help you